# Map [0,1] to [0,1) in floating point math

Tags: math, precision, numerical-methods

Suppose I have a function on floats:
`f` whose range is `[0, 1]`.

I'd like to create a function
`g` whose range is `[0, 1)`

such that
`f(x) < f(y) -> g(x) < g(y)`.

With finite precision floating point math, I can't get the range of `g` to be exactly `[0,1)`, but how close can I get, and how do I do it?

Comment: I don't see how this is possible unless you weaken your assumptions. You have `f(x) != f(y)` implies `g(x) != g(y)`, so the image of `g` must have cardinality greater than or equal to that of `f`. But `[0, 1)` has one fewer float in it than `[0, 1]`, so if `f` maps *onto* `[0, 1]`, no `g` satisfying your assumptions can exist.

Comment: Ahhhhh. Of course! I need to rethink this.

Comment: @MarkDickinson if you add your comment as an answer, I can mark it correct (which it is).